# Java EE application heap issue

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, heap-memory

We have used the eclipse memory analyzer and it shows the following things in the heap. The heap snapshot has been attached. Could this cause a memory leak in the future?

I am not able to pin point which file exactly is causing so many objects to be retained on the heap. Can you please provide some insight on this? We are using a Java EE application with the spring framework along with a tomcat 5.5 server. The database used is mysql.

Thanks in advance.

[image: The heap snapshot]

[image]

Comment: What is the question? What is worrying you?

Comment: There are a lot of objects retained on the heap. Will this cause an out of memory exception? It seemed to have happened once. I want to get to the root cause...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack doesn't look particularly worrisome if you'd ask me.

The entries shown are created by the Spring framework and are used to increase its performance. Since Spring, like many other modern Java frameworks, uses reflection a lot to couple beans, inject stuff, apply configuration etc, it would be a little slow if all spring beans where inspected over and over again. Spring therefor caches the results of this inspection.

Also note that a `WeakHashMap` is being used, which has special properties with respect to garbage collection (read its Javadocs to learn more about this).

Comment: The problem is the eclipse memory analyser shows 3 possible leak suspects which have retained about 3.5 mb of heap each. Could this indicate a possible memory leak?

Comment: Did MAT pinpoint that particular section as possible leak? I still wouldn't worry about some 10MB of memory usage, but simulate some load on your app (e.g. via JMeter), let it run for some time and inspect this particular section again. As the amount of beans in your app is finite, I would expect the results from introspection to be finite as well.

Comment: I have added another snapshot from the memory analyzer which shows the leak suspects? Is it normal that so much of heap space has been occupied?

Comment: What systems are you used to be programming for if I may ask? Embedded systems perhaps? For an AS 25.6MB is really not that much. Only if this is really growing to unmanageable proportions (say a couple of hundred MBs), you may have a problem.

Comment: Its a web application which performs some operations. It shows a list of companies along with their promotions, offers etc. Basically its a web app which shows information about the companies. We are using Arvixe VPS to host our application. This heap dump image pasted is only for a few users say about 5. And there are about 300 users using the website everyday. Will this heap space oocupied remain same when many users hit it? What i want to know is is this heap size occupied by the framework itself or is it due to the code?

Comment: What I actually meant, is what systems -you- worked on -before-? It's a long time ago that I saw someone getting spooked over a mere 23MB. Most frameworks will need a base level of initial memory. This is to read their config files, and cache various internal representations of your code. The only way to find out if there really is a problem is to run a JMeter or perhaps Selenium test with a few hundred users. Create/record a script that does some useful work and measure afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find if you really have a memory leak is to comapre it at various levels: 
1. take a heap memory snapshot once the application is started and no requests have been served.
2. Take multiple snapshots at various levels when requests are being served (in use application snapshot)
3. Take a snapshot after 3-4 min once all requests are processed.

If there is no memory leak 1 and 3 snapshots should be approximately same.

if they are not you can see which additional objects are occupying the memory. Start tracing from your custom packages rather than Spring or JDBC or core library packages.

Comment: This is something which I could try doing. Thank you